# Anime about a boy, who wants to be a geographer, has a large battle scar on his back

Tags: story-identification, anime

A boy has a large scar on his back from a battle, in which his brother and father died. The boy wants to be a geographer and so the mom  hires a world known assassin who is good at disguising himself. But the boy finds out that the assassin was disgusted as his butler, and the two go on an 3 month journey. 
Two details I remember, are that:

- The boy uses measurements to fight.
- The assassin has white hair and a fire sword.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: How did he use "measurements to fight"?

Comment: A similar ([now deleted](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/44991/whats-the-manga-name)) question was asked on Anime:SE about six months ago. The archived question reads; *"It's about a boy who witnesses his dad and brother die in battle. And now he's the head but his mom tries to get him assassinated. But he finds out and the assassin tries to attack but the boy uses measurements to dodge . And since the boy found out about the assassin the assassin is now forced to go on a journey with him. It's not a yaoi. The assassin also has ..."*

Comment: From the username, looks like the OP of the deleted question on Anime.SE is the same as this OP, though on the Anime.SE, OP mentioned *manga* instead.